# Draw a block of text to a certain position in the console?

Tags: c#, console-application

I know how to set the cursor position of the console, but upon creating a new line, the cursor moves back to the left side of the console.

How do I set the cursor position and write multiple lines while retaining the cursor's `x` coordinate?

Note: It is note an option for me to set the cursor position for every line, as my block of text changes size often.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void WriteLineKeepingIndent(string format, params object[] args)
{
    int x = Console.CursorLeft;
    Console.WriteLine(format, args);
    Console.CursorLeft = x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use one of

1. Before each **Console.WriteLine()** set **Console.CursorLeft**
2. Use **PadLeft** method on strings